# Пользовательское выделение в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Смысл в том, чтобы пользовательское выделение работало также, как и системное, а само системное выделение не показывалось.

```
int selectstart = RichTextBox.SelectionStart;
int selectend = RichTextBox.SelectionLength;
if (selectend >= 1)
   {
   RichTextBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
   RichTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
   RichTextBox.SelectionStart = selectstart + selectend;
   }
RichTextBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
```

Данный код работает только когда я выделяю дальше по тексту, но не работает в обратную сторону. Т.е. повел выделение вправо по тексту и не отпуская кнопку мыши, веду влево и снимаю это выделение. Уже пробовал внести дополнительные переменные, отнимать от начального значения, но не получилось. 
Я знаю, что мой алгоритм это скорее костыль, но просто надо создать свое выделение, ибо системное для моей программы не подходит.
Можете посоветовать как улучшить данный алгоритм или как создать свое кастомное выделение?

Comment: RTB предоставляется WinAPI, его класс - только обертка для .NET Поэтому от системного выделения вы не сможете отказаться. Можете заглянуть в исходники класса http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs,a71a91439f502a55